# How to reboot into CLI?

Tags: ubuntu, grub2, kde-neon

I need to perform some housekeeping on `/home`, so I figure I should reboot into CLI instead of into GUI.

How do I do that on **KDE Neon**?

For additional info, I'm using an UEFI system, GPT, and grub2.

Comment: Nevermind, I found the how-to here: https://askubuntu.com/a/859637/11952

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just followed the instructions on https://askubuntu.com/a/859637/11952, written by [WinEunuuchs2Unix](https://askubuntu.com/users/307523/wineunuuchs2unix) and copied below:

---

Yes you can. As described here ([ubuntuhandbook.org - Boot into text console ubuntu](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/01/boot-into-text-console-ubuntu-linux-14-04/)) you need to edit `/etc/default/grub` to have the next boot end up in text mode. In summary you will set these parameters:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"
GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

After saving changes you need to run:

```
sudo update-grub
sudo systemctl enable multi-user.target --force
sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target
```

### Undoing text-mode

To undo `sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target` simply type

```
sudo systemctl enable graphical.target --force
sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target
```